# Unsubscribe event from asynchronous wcf operation

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm working on WP app, which use wcf service. WP works only with asynchronous method, so after adding service reference all methods are async. I want to ask you, when I subscribe event, can I unsubscribe event OnSendDataCompleted method like in my example?

```
serviceClient.SendDataCompleted += OnSendDataCompleted;
serviceClient.SendData(params);

void OnSendDataCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e){
    serviceClient.SendDataCompleted -= OnSendDataCompleted;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you use C# 5 async/await?

Comment: yes you can.To test just set breakpoint and count how many times it will be invoked. But if you subscribe more than once (ie subcribe on each button click) this doesnt guarantee your `OnSendDataCompleted` will be called 1 time.

Comment: have you tried the code you have posted? I mean the one with unsubscribe

Comment: Yes I've tried the code and it's working, but I was not sure, if it is good approach how to unsubscribe the event. The event is subscribed only once.